# Why is the display of QgsMessageBar delayed?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, interface

When a function is called - a file is tested for existence.  This checksum pushes a messageBar() object for both circumstances (True/False), yet the actual bar does not 
display in MapCanvas until after the subsequent exec_() is called and finished running.

```
def callUtherPendragonsSon(self):
    holyGrailFile = 'C:\ALongWayFrom\camelot.csv'
    if os.path.exists(holyGrailFile):
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Notice", "You will need many coconuts...",\
                                            level=QgsMessageBar.INFO, duration=3)
        beginTheJourney = gatherProvisionsAndMen()
        beginTheJourney.exec_()
    else:
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Warning", "There is no grail :( ",\
                                            level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=3)
        return
```

Is there a means to assure the message bar is pushed prior to calling the exec_() ?

***UPDATE (1):***

As it turns out, a command in the external Ui gatherProvisionsAndMen()'s **init**  is causing the trouble.  It is a data-thirsty function call, and seems to supersede the messagebar (even though it is executed thereafter).   The messageBar itself is intended to preliminarily notify the user of this nested 'lengthy process' - but it seems such a notice needs to take place in another manner...

Perhaps I hold a misunderstanding in the logistics of programming but,

*wouldn't the call to push a QgsMessageBar() need to complete before moving forward and executing the external Ui?*

Comment: Do you mean you only see the bar after you've closed the dialog? Cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: The bar is only displayed after the external Ui-dialog has passed the *.show() command.  e.g.-both the messageBar and Ui appear simultaneously, rather then (as intended) the former before the later.

Comment: Still cannot replicate it. In my test plugin, I added a for loop in between to delay the `show()` call, however, the message appears immediately after it's called.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the success you mention.  Is it possible that my QgisVer (2.7-Dev) is @ cause?

Comment: Please download this [test plugin](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/tmp/SyncQGISWithDir.zip) and let me know if you still face the problem.

Comment: First off, that looks like a useful plugin!  Secondly, the messageBar popped up immediately, and very shortly thereafter the Ui.  I have a feeling that it has to do with the external Ui in my case.  In the init function of the Ui, I have a couple crunchy (invested) processes - and they must be causing a backup of actions?

Comment: That could be the case. Perhaps you could try with a simple version and see if it gets better, i.e., try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Your advice indeed focuses in on the trouble spot.  A command to write a *.csv within the init of the Ui is the culprit.  Really, the point of this message bar is to let the user know that there will be some delay time in opening the Ui.  Hence the experienced delay.  It seems alternative notifications to the user will have to be discovered.

Comment: You could show a progress bar, either within your dialog or within a `QgsMessageBar` itself.

Comment: Considering the QgsMessageBar pushed before the Ui does not seem to work - perhaps a QProgressBar initialized within the plugin BEFORE the data-thirsty process is the solution...

Comment: What if you initialize your dialog in the `__init__()` plugin function? I think that's the recommended way. However, it depends on your plugin's logic, of course.

Comment: Rightly so!  Some preliminary functions must be ran in order to populate settings, which are called  just prior to the final *.show() command in the Ui.  I wonder if a QThread with the lagged function in question might be an alternative.

Comment: I wish there was a way to check the status of a QgsMessageBar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put dummy **print 'xxx'** statement immediately after **self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage** call.

Comment: I have found that if the Python plugin console is not open during such scripted prints - errors arise.  Maybe due to the version I  have implemented?

Comment: Describe an error message please.

Comment: "  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GraphicGroundwater\loadParticleTracks.py", line 265, in constructShapefile
    print newPathGroups
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Comment: You are right about Python plugin console: my solution works only if this console is open.

Comment: To debug an error just try to disable/enable installed plugin again... not sure what is the real cause of this error.

Comment: SOLUTION: please use **self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage()** just before **self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage()** call. And if you need, also **self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().clearMessage()**

Comment: Thank you for this!  I have a lot of updates to make to implement this - but it seems to help alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, just say to the main window to repaint itself after pushing your message with the `repaint` function :

```
 self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Please wait...", level=QgsMessageBar.INFO, duration=0)
 self.iface.mainWindow().repaint()
 # Do something that takes time
 time.sleep(5)
 self.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
```